# Unable to mount internal hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I can't access my internal hard drives other than the root partition. When I open my hard drive, I get the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/sam/i Stuffs:    
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/sam/i Stuffs"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:  

The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5':
  Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount
  option.
```

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Boot into Windows and then restart it (do not shutdown)
- In the GRUB menu select Ubuntu and boot  it. After Ubuntu has booted up, open the hard drive - it will open.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have windows installed in that partition. If so the problem is that windows is hibernating. In order to be able to access the partition you need to perform a normal shutdown of the system.

Windows 7 and earlier:

- Shutdown

Windows 8:

- This system has a hybrid shutdown method, a lot like hibernate. Follow the instructions in the links bellow:

Permanent Fix: http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/

- This will make Windows8 do a normal shutdown every time. Windows boot time may increase.

Optional Method: http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/

- Create a shortcut that will let you do a normal shutdown when you want to access the partition from Ubuntu. Affects Windows 8 boot time only once.

Restart Method:

- Windows 8 performs a normal shutdown when you request to restart the computer. Therefore if you restart you will also be able to access the partition if you boot into Ubuntu during restart by selecting Ubuntu in the grub menu. Note: If this doesn't work let me know.